# Google Cloud Text-to-speech API: highlight text as it is being played on BROWSER

Tags: google-speech-api, google-text-to-speech

The question is on a **Browser** not Android (since the tag seems to suggest android text to speech).

I am using the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API (https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) to convert some dynamic text and send the response to the browser. I have been successful in doing it, by sending the response as a base64 string and playing it using:

```
let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.src = base64str;
audio.play();
```

Is there a way in which I can display/highlight the text (which is also being sent as part of the response from the server and available to the browser) as the voice is being spoken? Thanks